# Showing New and Old by Date using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

long time no chat, I am  running into a situation in where a formula I wrote up seems not to be working correctly. I know it's probably me, but logic based programming seems to be the bane of my existence.

`=IF(D1>2010,"New",IF(D1<2010,"Old",""))`

Is the formula in question, now if I got this down correctly, which I thought I did, is that if D1 is greater than the year 2010 the cell would say `New`, and if it's less than 2010, it would say `Old`.

It's not working, for some reason I can't figure out why.

I have a similar formula that works:

`=IF($B155<>"","Full",IF($J155<>"","Full","Empty"))`

I figured the logic would be similar, it seems I'm wrong. Can someone help me solve this simple quandary, logic based math has never been my strong suit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If D1=2010, there's no true condition in IF clauses, and the result will be a blank cell (`""`).

`=IF(D1>=2010,"New",IF(D1<2010,"Old",""))` should do the trick.

If D1 is formatted as a Date, the following formula will give the desired result:

```
=IF(YEAR(D1)>=2010,"New",IF(YEAR(D1)<2010,"Old",""))
```